# How to draw this simple figure in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

[image]

This is related to wireless sensor networks. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.sx. Can you show us what you have already tried (as a complete, compilable code example) and describe what your problems are? That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: This is not a simple figure, need to write some lines of codes to achieve it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As starting point:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
box/.style = {draw, fill=#1, align=center,
              text width=5em, text height=2ex, text depth=0.25ex,
              outer sep=0pt}
                        ]
\draw[thick] (0,0) node (n1) [above left] {Sender} -- ++ (7,0);
\node (n2) [box=green,above] at (3.5,0) {packet};
%
\draw[thick] (0,-1) node (n3) [above left] {Receiver} -- ++ (7,0);
\node (n4) [box=green,above] at (3.5,-1) {packet};
\node (n5) [box=red, left=of n4]    {idle};;
\node (n6) [box=red, right=of n4]   {idle};;
   \end{tikzpicture}

% second example
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 0pt,
box/.style = {draw, fill=#1, align=center,
              text width=5em, text height=2ex, text depth=0.25ex,
              outer sep=0pt}
                        ]
\draw[thick] (0,0) node (n1) [above left] {Sender A} -- ++ (7,0);
\node (n2) [box=green,above] at (2,0) {packet};
%
\draw[thick] (0,-1) node (n3) [above left] {Sender B} -- ++ (7,0);
\node (n4) [box=green,above] at (3,-1) {packet};
%
\draw[thick] (0,-2) node (n5) [above left] {Receiver} -- ++ (7,0);
    \scoped[text=white]
{
\node (n6) [box=green, above] at (2,-2) {packet};
\node (n4) [box=red,above]    at (3,-2) {garbage};
}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
For exercise is added one more example.

Comment: @Nitin Chamoli, I add another example.